# Answer to a deleted question being used as review audit in first posts queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, deleted-questions, review-audits

I just got the [below](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts#first-posts/2764363?&_suid=1377083843154044432367945476486) review audit for an answer. While I know audits are supposed to be easy, I'm guessing this is too easy.

I'm suggesting the audit-selection should be updated to either exclude answers to deleted questions, or at least be amended so it doesn't show.

> [image: Answer to no question]

Comment: Indeed the question has been deleted and because you have less than 10K on [so] you simply can't see it.

Comment: What is weird is that I can see the question now, if I click the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will be excluding answers to deleted questions from the audit reviews going forward.

Comment: Looks like this [isn't quite fixed yet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/263155/456814).